# minidlna start. It is working, but I don't get any data. (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Tags: 20.04, accessibility, minidlna

I cannot find any solution.

Output of `journalctl`:

```
mei 21 11:33:30 tvnr systemd[1]: Starting LSB: minidlna server...
mei 21 11:33:31 tvnr systemd[1]: Started LSB: minidlna server.
```

Output of `service minidlna status`:

```
    minidlna.service - LSB: minidlna server
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/minidlna; generated)
     Active: active (exited) since Thu 2020-05-21 11:36:26 CEST; 11s ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Process: 4934 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/minidlna start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

mei 21 11:36:26 tvnr systemd[1]: Starting LSB: minidlna server...
mei 21 11:36:26 tvnr systemd[1]: Started LSB: minidlna server.
```

Output of `pgrep minidlna|xargs ps`:

```
    PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
   1388 ?        Ssl    0:00 minidlnad -f /var/snap/minidlna-escoand/19/minidlna.conf -P /var/snap/minidlna-escoand/common/minidlna.pid
```

I tried to change `/etc:default` and added mijn username, but there is no change:

```
# Defaults for minidlna initscript
# sourced by /etc/init.d/minidlna
# installed at /etc/default/minidlna by the maintainer scripts

# These options can be set to modify the behavior of the minidlna init script.
# The options commented out show the default values.

# Start the daemon if set to "yes"
START_DAEMON="yes"

# Path to the configuration file
CONFIGFILE="/etc/minidlna.conf"

# Path to the log file
#LOGFILE="/var/log/minidlna.log"

# User and group the daemon should run as
USER="gerda-johan"
#GROUP="minidlna"

# Additional options that are passed to the daemon
# We pass -r option to do soft non-destructive rebuild on every start-up.
# If your systerm restarts often, you might want to remove this.
DAEMON_OPTS="-r"
```

I cannot understand what is wrong?
It is working and the database exist, but I cannot see anything here :(

Maybe a little help can do a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

The output that you provided for "service minidlna status" indicates that the process started but exited (see "Active (exited)" in your log).

It is probably obvious to you, but make sure the USER that you are intending to run this as (ie. gerda-johan) actually is a valid user id in the linux system.  Also, see this thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/debian/comments/gha898/minidlna_setup_notes/

Comment: thanks it was this i already found this issue